# Gmail lock screen notifications don't appear on iPod Touch, but the device still wakes from sleep

Tags: ios, email, ipod-touch, sleep-wake, gmail

I've got the Gmail iOS app installed on my iPod Touch 5. Also, I have set the app to only show notifications for "Important" emails (which are indicated with a yellow tab in the web version of Gmail). Sometimes, when I get an important email, the email will show (as expected) on my iPod Touch's lock screen as a notification. However, sometimes the iPod Touch will wake from sleep to show the lock screen, but no notification appears.

Is this something that I can fix on my end? Or is it a bug with the Gmail iOS app itself?

Comment: What are your settings for gmail in settings-> notifications?  Also does this happen for 'important' messages? Or others?

Comment: All notification types are enabled for my Gmail app. This happens only for "Important" Gmail emails. It doesn't happen for non-Important emails, and it does not happen for any other app, at least that I can see.